# custom vendor shipping fee in custom cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a vendor website with 10 to 12 sellers. Each seller has a different shipping fee. Sellers can select shipping fees or minimum shipping fees by region. I have already setup it on my website. I am using dokan pro plugin and woocommerce.

Now I want it on my cart and checkout page. Different seller shipping fees are shown on the cart page. I want to show the shipping fee in a seller loop.

My vendor loop looks like this
vendor name is A
Product 1
Product 2
Product 3
Shipping Fee - 20

vendor Name B
Product 4
Product 5
Product 6
Shipping Fee - 10

I want to show the exact shipping fee that the seller applies in the seller dashboard.

$values ) {
            $vendor_id  = reset($values); // The vendor id
            $store_info  = dokan_get_store_info( $vendor_id ); // Get the store data
            $store_name  = $store_info['store_name'];          // Get the store name
            $store_url = dokan_get_store_url( $vendor_id );  // Get the store URL (if needed)

            ?>

```
    <div class="custom_bg_style">
            <ul>
            <!-- Store name display -->
                <li  style = "margin-left: 25px" class="store-name"><strong><?php echo $store_name; ?></strong></li>
            </ul>

       
        <?php
        // 2nd Loop the cart items for the vendor name

        foreach( $values as $cart_item_key => $vendor_id) {
            
            // Retreive the cart item from the cart item key
            $cart_item = $car_items[$cart_item_key];
            ?>

            <!-- Product display -->
            <?php
            $_product   = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product', $cart_item['data'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
            $product_id = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_product_id', $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
            $product_permalink = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_permalink', $_product->is_visible() ? $_product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) : '', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );
            ?>
                        <?php
                            echo apply_filters( // phpcs:ignore WordPress.Security.EscapeOutput.OutputNotEscaped
                                'woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link',
                                sprintf(
                                    '<a style="color: #id1e22; " href="%s" class="remove custom_trash_icon" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s"><i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    </a>',
                                    esc_url( wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
                                    esc_html__( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
                                    esc_attr( $product_id ),
                                    esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
                                ),
                                $cart_item_key
                            );
                        ?>
            <div class="product-thumbnail" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; display: inline-block; margin: 0px 15px">
                <?php
                    $thumbnail = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_thumbnail', $_product->get_image(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                    if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
                        echo $thumbnail; // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                        } else {
                            printf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $thumbnail ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                        }
                ?>
            </div>
            <div style="display: inline-block;">
                <span class="product-name" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                        <?php
                        if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
                            echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . '&nbsp;' );
                        } else {
                            echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $_product->get_name() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) );
                        }

                        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_name', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

                        // Meta data.
                        // echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.

                        // Backorder notification.
                        if ( $_product->backorders_require_notification() && $_product->is_on_backorder( $cart_item['quantity'] ) ) {
                            echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_backorder_notification', '<p class="backorder_notification">' . esc_html__( 'Available on backorder', 'woocommerce' ) . '</p>', $product_id ) );
                        }
                        ?>
                </span>
                <br>
                        
                <span class="product-price" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Price', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                    <?php
                        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', WC()->cart->get_product_price( $_product ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                    ?></br>
                    <?php
                        // if (isset($vendor_shipping_fees[$store_name])) {
                        //  echo '<style>
                        //  @import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.4.0/css/all.min.css");
                        //  </style>';
                        //  echo '<span clsaa="nextday_delivery_date_widget">';
                        //  echo '<span style="margin-bottom: 0px; font-size: 12px;"><i class="fa-solid fa-circle-check" style = "color: #00A3E7; "></i> Next Day Delivery (FREE on orders over $49.00) </span>';
                        //  echo '</span';
                        // }

                        
                    ?>                                      
                </span>
                <br>
                <span class="product-quantity" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                    <?php
                        if ( $_product->is_sold_individually() ) {
                            $min_quantity = 1;
                            $max_quantity = 1;
                        } else {
                            $min_quantity = 0;
                            $max_quantity = $_product->get_max_purchase_quantity();
                        }

                        $product_quantity = woocommerce_quantity_input(
                            array(
                                'input_name'   => "cart[{$cart_item_key}][qty]",
                                'input_value'  => $cart_item['quantity'],
                                'max_value'    => $max_quantity,
                                'min_value'    => $min_quantity,
                                'product_name' => $_product->get_name(),
                            ),
                            $_product,
                            false
                        );

                        echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_quantity', $product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.
                        ?>
                </span>
            </div>
            <br>
            <?php
        } // End of 2nd Loop
        ?>
        Display shipping fee here
        
        </div>
        <?php
    } // End of 1st Loop
```

?>

Comment: here is the vendor loop full code

https://notepad.pw/IUfy6OQ7WOzgNBlfMMUj